# Sending email on edit, all signs point to go but its not

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation

I'm about to go insane. I've been working on this for hours and everything says it should be working and the logs say that it was successful, but yet no email is sent or received. I have checked all the spam filters, spam folders, Spam tins, and PAM spray cans and none of them have a record of blocking the email from going to Matt's inbox or Matt's bosses inbox.

When an opportunity is assigned to Matt (dropbox with names located in column 5), I want to send him an email, with all the information in that row, saying so. Matt's boss also needs to receive a cc copy of the email to track it. I have linked my email to the ownership of the sheet, so do I need to specify the origin email as well? I set up a separate installable trigger to run sendEmailEdit on edit.

```
​function sendEmailEdit(e){

  if (e.range.columnStart != 5 || e.value != "Matt") return;
  
    const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,11).getValues();
    let opportunity = rData [0][0];
    let job_name = rData [0][1];
    let address = rData [0][2];
    let client =  rData [0][3];
    let estimator =  rData [0][4];
    let due_date = rData [0][5];
    let due_time =  rData [0][6];
    let now = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US");
    let msg = "Opportunity"  + " " + opportunity + " "  + job_name + " "  + address + " "  + client + " "  + estimator + " " + due_date + " "  + due_time + " "  + "assigned on" + " "  + now ;
    var recipient = "matt@test.com";
    var subject = "Opportunity Assigned" + opportunity;
    var body = msg;
    var options = {
    cc: "mattboss@test.com"
  }
 Logger.log(msg);
MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)
}
```

I have tried to change parameters, changing variable to constant, changed the edit range, everything that I can think of. Run logs say that everything was executed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Used this to test:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast('Entry');
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 5 && e.value == "Matt") {
    e.source.toast("Gate1")
    const [a,b,c,d,E,f,g] = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, 11).getValues().flat();
    let now = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US");
    let msg = "Opportunity" + " " + a + " " + b + " " + c + " " + d + " " + E + " " + f + " " + g + " " + "assigned on" + " " + now;
    var recipient = "matt@test.com";
    var subject = "Opportunity Assigned" + a;
    var body = msg;
    var options = {
      cc: "mattboss@test.com"
    }
    Logger.log('r: %s s: %s m: %s cc: %s', recipient, subject, body, options.cc);
    //MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)
  }
}
```

This works on a simple trigger.